# Python Package Module Not Found SVN Import

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, python-module

Imported the [SVN Package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svn), going to the following PYTHONPATH confirmed by import sys >>> sys.path:

\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages

This is where all packages are stored and other packages within this directory will import appropriately in Py.

When I open Py in Terminal, and  Import SVN, it is producing an import error, No Module Name. Tested this in Terminal, IPython, Bash, Jupyter Notebook.

The only thing I can ascertain is this is an issue perhaps with a third party library...out of ideas at this point. There does not appear to be another option for a SVN module, need this for script to grep SVN. If there's another way to do this without this package, welcome other ideas as well.

Thank you in advance for any help or ideas.

Comment: So you installed it, right? And then you ran python and tried `import svn`? Make sure to be specific about what you tried.

Comment: Yes - did install it....  just (FINALLY) figured this out: the tar file had all the install folders rolled into one in a sub directory - extracted these files, and then moved to the top level. Also import to note - unlike other modules, this one required me to run setup.py from the CLI not sure why this was needed versus other imports.  Thanks @FamousJamous for the quick reply.